# How to set the allowed url length limit for a kubernetes nginx(error code: 414, uri too large)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We have deployed our microservices in the k8 cluster and we have also configured ingress resources for them as we are accessing it from outside of k8 cluster. When we make a request with size larger then 2900 character we get back an: error code 414: uri too large. We searched on the internet and found about nginx settings which can help us in solving this problem

```
Syntax: large_client_header_buffers number size ;
Default: large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;
Context: http, server
```

Since we are using nginx ingress, We checked the documentation on [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#proxy-buffers-number) online resource but could not find corresponding settings. Can somebody help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [this page](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/) for all nginx-ingress config.

Add the values in the `ConfigMap` and they will get picked up automatically.

The exact value you are looking for is: `large-client-header-buffers`

Comment: We want corresponding annotations because we want to override at the ingress level of service

Comment: There does not seem to be out of box solution for this. Best I could find was [custom-anotations](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.10.0/examples/custom-annotations#step-1---customize-the-template).